# Using readlines() to write a template txt file to 'x' new files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a template txt file. This template needs to be written as 10 new files where I can then make amendments to each file based on certain conditions (not relevant to the question).

I read my template file as follows:

```
with open('template.txt', 'r') as template_file:
     file_lines = template_file.readlines()
     file_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file_lines]
     for i in range(10):
         new_file = open('output_%s' % i, 'w')
         new_file.write(file_lines)
     new_file.close()
```

It won't work as I cannot write a list to each file, it must be a string, but I don't know how to get every element from that list to be written in the same file 10 times...Each time I try it a different way I end up getting each line on different files, rather than all lines in all files.

Something wrong in my logic I cannot work out.

Another way I can do it as :

```
template_file = open('template.txt', 'r')
template_lines = template_file.read()

for i in range(10):
    new_files = open('output_%s' % i, 'w')
    new_files.write(template_lines)
```

But I want to be able amendment particular lines which makes it more convenient to write into each new file line by line (via readlines())

Answer (score 2):

You can use the python method `writelines(<iterable>)` on the fileobject.

Something like:

```
with open('template.txt', 'r') as template_file:
    file_lines = template_file.readlines()
    file_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file_lines]
    for i in range(10):
        with open('output_%s' % i, 'w') as new_file:
            new_file.write_lines(file_lines)
```

Also not sure you need the `rstrip('\n')` as `readlines()` already should be removing newlines.

Comment: Yes you are right... writelines did the job.. and I removed the stripping of lines.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try indenting the `new_file.close()` so it's saved after every for loop

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you want to achieve. Anyways, here is a code snippet of how you can write the same line to every one of the 10 files:

```
with open('template.txt', 'r') as template_file:
    file_lines = template_file.readlines()
    file_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file_lines]
    for line in file_lines:
        for i in range(10):
            new_file = open('output_%s' % i, 'a') # appending content
            new_file.write(line)
            new_file.close()
```

or even this, if you prefer:

```
with open('template.txt', 'r') as template_file:
    file_lines = template_file.readlines()
    file_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file_lines]
    for i in range(10):
        new_file = open('output_%s' % i, 'w')
        for line in file_lines:
            new_file.write(line)
        new_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `writelines` method did the job.

```
with open(TRANSFER_SKED, 'r') as template_file:
    file_lines = template_file.readlines()
    # file_lines = [i.rstrip('\n') for i in file_lines]

    for i in range(10):
        with open('output_%s.txt' % i, 'w') as new_file:
            new_file.writelines(file_lines)
```